# Change default error message when enter non digit in a textbox requires integer

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application using MVVM. It has a textbox which needs an integer. The XAML of that text box is as below

```
<TextBox Name="textBoxElementWeight" 
    Text="{Binding ElementName=listBoxElement, Path=SelectedItem.Weight,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationTextBoxTemplate}"/>
```

The view model implements interface INotifyDataErrorInfo.

When I delete the text to enter a new one, it says "Value '' could not be converted."

How do I change this error message to mine? Ex: "Please enter a number."

The whole Visual Studio solution can be downloaded [here](http://www.4phuong.vn/Hydroponic.rar)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to provide custom validation messages is to implement either the [`IDataErrorInfo` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [`INotifyDataErrorInfo` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) in your data object class. I won't go into a detailed implementation here because there are many tutorials that are easily found online, however, I'll explain briefly.

When implementing the `IDataErrorInfo` Interface, you have an indexer property that you need to implement that takes in a `string` property name. It can be used like this:

```
public override string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        string error = string.Empty;
        if (propertyName == "Name" && Name.IsNullOrEmpty()) error = "You must enter the Name field.";
        else if (propertyName == "Name" && Name.Length > 100) error = "That name is too long.";
        ...
        return error;
    }
}
```

When implementing the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` Interface, you use `DataAnnotation` attributes on each property, like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter the Name field.")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "That name is too long.")]
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { if (value != name) { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name", "Errors"); } }
}
```

Please search online for further information on implementing these interfaces.

Comment: Still does not work. Here is my implementation

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a number.")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "That name is too long.")]
        public float Weight
        {
            get { return this.Element.Weight; }
            set
            {
                if (value == this.Element.Weight)
                    return;
                this.Element.Weight = value;
                this.ValidateWeight();
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Weight");
            }
        }

Comment: You need to fully implement one of the interfaces to make it work.

Comment: It's already implemented function GetErros. Here is my code:
        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || !this.validationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                return null;

            return this.validationErrors[propertyName];
        }

Comment: The code (Visual Studio solution) was already added at the end of my question.